# Why doesn't this PHP preg_replace() work?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I've got some bad MySQL entries that I need to fix.  I'm trying to do so in PHP.

**What I've got**:

`a whole bunch of text with no numbers Entry #:`**2439**`. a whole bunch of text Click here to blah blah blah`

**What I want**:

`a whole bunch of text with no numbers Entry #:`**2439**`. a whole bunch of text <BR><A href="somepage.php?entry_no=`**2439**`">Click here to blah blah blah</A>`

**My PHP code**:

```
$fixed = preg_replace('/(.*)(\d*)(.*)(Click here.*)/i',"$1$2$3<BR><A href=\"somepage.php?entry_no=$2\">$4</A>",$originalData);
```

For some reason, this is what I get:

`a whole bunch of text with no numbers Entry #:`**2439**`. a whole bunch of text <BR><A href="somepage.php?entry_no=">Click here to blah blah blah</A>`

The $2 is not giving me the number the second time.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Don’t use “Click here” (<http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere>).

Comment: Thanks guys, but I didn't design this system.  I'm just trying to fix it.

Comment: Is it really that hard fix the URL manually?

Comment: @Gumbo: No, but that's not my call unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the first match is being greedy:

Given this input, here's what each part is matching:

```
a whole bunch of text with no numbers Entry #: 2439. a whole bunch of text Click here to blah blah blah

(.*)    // "a whole bunch of text with no numbers Entry #: 2439. a whole bunch of text "
(\d*)   // "" (0 or more numbers)
(.*)    // "" (0 or more characters)
```

All you have to do is make the first match non-greedy:

```
(.*?)(\d+)(.*)(Click here.*)
```

Also, since you're defining the regex inside a string, you need to escape your slashes:

```
"/(.*?)(\\d*) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I added the ? to the first match and escaped the backslash, but it still returns the same results.

Comment: Got it!  Using what you gave me, I tried changing the first match to (.*Entry #: ) and it worked.  Thanks very much.

Comment: oh - you could also change the \d* to \d+ to make sure it matches at least one number.